# selecting two spans on hover with css

Tags: html, css

I tried a lot but I'm stuck.

Actually, I want to hover on **"Intro word"** and as a result [hover results must applied on the square box]

```css
.navbars>ul>li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:20px;
}
.navbars>ul>li>a{
  /*color: aliceblue;*/ /* commented by question reveiwer to have a viewable snippet */
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box-nav{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
.box-nav-content{
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
span:hover{
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbars">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Intro </span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">About</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Work</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Clients</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Let's Talk</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `Intro word` your fist link? What is `square box` exactly? The `box-nav`?

Comment: your css code is not fully shown you have not added navbar style, anyway would you try to add `display: block;` to the span:hover css and lemme know how it's going on ?

Comment: `.box-nav` are `span` with opacity: 0... And should be opacity: 1 on hover... But they are empty in the code you posted and there is no `.box-nav-content`... I guess you focussed too much on the minimal and not enought on the reproducible aspects of [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: sqaure box is nav-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the sibbling selector  [**`+`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)  .

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element.

```css
.navbars>ul>li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:20px;
}
.navbars>ul>li>a{
  /*color: aliceblue;*/ /* commented by question reveiwer to have a viewable snippet */
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box-nav{
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: black /* black to see me here */ /*white*/;
  display: inline-block !important;
  opacity: 0;
}
.box-nav-content{
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block !important;
}
span:hover + span{
  opacity: 1  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbars">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Intro </span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">About</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Work</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Clients</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="box-nav-content">Let's Talk</span><span class="box-nav"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```